# How to invoke a eclipse plugin through external API or through command prompt?

Tags: java, api, eclipse-plugin

I have a simple hello world plugin created in Eclipse SDK (4.6-Neon). I want to trigger this plugin from an external API (like when I hit the API- http://localhost:8080/startPlugin) it should run the plugin (considering the Eclipse is already open). Is there a way to it? I've tried many links but couldn't find any solution. It would help if I can trigger this plugin from command prompt also if it is possible.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. Eclipse isn't a web server and doesn't listen on any port. Neither does it have a way to do this via the command prompt.